# How do I validate a variable against multple database tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

Does anyone know how to check a a variable against all database table with columns storing the same type of information? I have a poorly designed database that stores ssn in over 60 tables within one database. some of the variations of columns in the various tables include:

app_ssn

ca_ssn

cand_ssn

crl_ssn

cu_ssn

emtaddr_ssn

re_ssn

sfcart_ssn

sfordr_ssn

socsecno

ssn

Ssn

SSN

I want to create a stored procedure that will accept a value and check it against every table that has 'ssn' in the name.Does anyone have idea as to how to do this?

Comment: Not really sure what your question is here. What do you mean by "check it"? FWIW, you should NEVER store SSN in plain text. I have a bad feeling you are doing it more than 60 times.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is find out if a ssn number exist in different tables with the same database.

Comment: To do that you will need to run a query against each table. Do you have a defined list of column names you want to look at? What do you want for output?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is some research. But here is where you can start;

```
    SELECT tbl.NAME AS TableName
    ,cl.NAME AS ColumnName
    ,IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS ID
INTO #ColumnsToLoop
FROM sys.tables tbl
JOIN sys.columns cl ON cl.object_id = tbl.object_id
```

This will give you the table / column relation then you can simply build a dynamic SQL string based on each row in the query above (basically loop it) and use EXEC or sp_execsql. So basically;

```
DECLARE @Loop int = (select min(ID) From #ColumnsToLoop),@MX int = (Select  MAX(ID) From #ColumnsToLoop)

WHILE(@Loop<=@MX)
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 'SQL String'

//Construct the dynamic SQL String

EXEC(@SQL);

SET @Loop += 1

END
```

Comment: @SeanLange yeah, correct. However, I do not know how much data size we are talking about so I would rather have him not run it all at once. The stored procedure he is going to create will probably be used by something else so I would rather have it provide it in batches.

Comment: How can you generate strings and exec strings without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

-- I assume that table/column names don't need to be surrounded by square braces. You may want to save matches in a table - I just select them. I also assume ssn is a char.

```
alter proc  proc1 
@search1 varchar(500)
as
begin
set nocount on

declare @strsql varchar(500)
declare @curtable sysname
declare @prevtable sysname
declare @column sysname

select top 1 @curtable= table_schema+'.'+table_name, @column=column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
where CHARINDEX('ssn',column_name) > 0
order by table_schema+'.'+table_name +column_name

-- make sure that at least one column has ssn in the column name
if @curtable is not null
begin
while (1=1)
begin
set @strsql = 'select * from ' +@curtable +' where '+''''+@search1+''''+ ' = '+@column
print @strsql
```

-- any matches for passed in ssn will match here...

```
exec (@strsql)

set @prevtable = @curtable+@column
select top 1 @curtable= table_schema+'.'+table_name, @column=column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
where CHARINDEX('ssn',column_name) > 0
and table_schema+'.'+table_name +column_name> @prevtable
order by table_schema+'.'+table_name +column_name
-- when we run out of columns that contain ssn we are done...
if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    break

end

end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I went a little too crazy with this one, but let me know. I thought it would best the primary key of the search results with the table name so you could join it to your tables. I also managed to do it without a single cursor or loop.

```
DECLARE @SSN VARCHAR(25) = '%99%',
        @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH CTE_PrimaryKeys
AS
(
SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG,
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        TABLE_NAME,
        column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE D
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
),
CTE_Columns
AS
(
    SELECT  A.*,
            CONCAT(A.TABLE_CATALOG,'.',A.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',A.TABLE_NAME) AS FullTableName,
            CASE WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPrimaryKey
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
    LEFT JOIN CTE_PrimaryKeys B
    ON      A.TABLE_CATALOG = B.TABLE_CATALOG
        AND A.TABLE_SCHEMA = B.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME
        AND A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
),
CTE_Select
AS
(
SELECT
        'SELECT ' + 

        --This returns the pk_col casted as Varchar and the table name in another columns
        STUFF((SELECT ',CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS pk_col,''' + B.TABLE_NAME + ''' AS Table_Name'
        FROM CTE_Columns B 
        WHERE   A.Table_Name = B.TABLE_NAME
                AND B.IsPrimaryKey = 1  
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

        + ' FROM ' + fullTableName + 

        --This is where I list the columns where LIKE desired SSN
        ' WHERE ' + 
        STUFF((SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ''' + @SSN + ''' OR '
        FROM CTE_Columns B 
        WHERE   A.Table_Name = B.TABLE_NAME
                --This is where I filter so I only get desired columns
                AND (
                        --Uncomment the Collate if your database is case sensitive
                        COLUMN_NAME /*COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS*/ LIKE '%ssn%'

                        --list your column Names that don't have ssn in them
                        --OR COLUMN_NAME IN ('col1','col2')
                    )
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,0,'') AS Selects
FROM CTE_Columns A
GROUP BY A.FullTableName,A.TABLE_NAME
)


--Unioning them all together and getting rid of last trailing "OR "
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@sql,'') + SUBSTRING(selects,1,LEN(selects) - 3) + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) --new line for easier debugging
FROM CTE_Select
WHERE selects IS NOT NULL


--Look at your code
SELECT SUBSTRING(@sql,1,LEN(@sql) - 11)
```